# How to save file image in express js using ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ng-file-upload

i am new in nodejs development and express
I learn MEAN stack nad now i don`t know how i can do this staff in n
In my route i have this code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/public/uploads/' });

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.file);
   res.status(200).json({ file: req.file});
});
module.exports = router;
```

But i saving not image. How i can save an image file? I mean some decode function or what?

In console i see this :

```
{ fieldname: 'file',
 originalname: 'my.jpg',
 encoding: '7bit',
 mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
 destination: '/home/path/mean/public/uploads/',
 filename: '8b6256d4af77641c844480f05806e959',
 path: '/home/path/mean/public/uploads/8b6256d4af77641c844480f05806e959',
 size: 19486 
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are getting a filename, path, and size, the file is being saved. Is the file not in path specified?

Comment: the file here, but not *.jpg/.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this code works for me. Right now i need to think how i would be save the image in collection of new post.
Smth like - i click the save image and save image on folder and after response i my ng-model will be  post.image = response.image, after i save all body of post in collection....
I don`t know, in PHP it will be in one reuqest :) I am very new with nodejs, it is just for fun, not for work. I like JavaScript. :)

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

var fs = require('fs');


fs.writeFile('public/uploads/image.jpg', req.file.buffer, 'ascii', 
 function  (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var multer = require('multer'); 

var storage = multer.diskStorage({  
    destination: function (req, file, cb) { 
        cb(null, 'public/upload')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});
```

This code helped me to achieve the goal. it will store the image with random name and the extension.